# pyramid_beaker session does not terminate after 30 minutes

Tags: pyramid, beaker

I installed python_beaker, added it into include:

```
session_factory = session_factory_from_settings(settings)
config = Configurator(settings=settings, session_factory=session_factory)
config.include('pyramid_beaker')
```

Added into development.ini these settings:

```
session.type = file
session.data_dir = /tmp/sessions/data
session.lock_dir = /tmp/sessions/lock
session.key = key
session.secret = secret
session.cookie_on_exception = true
```

But the session never ends. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail how it doesn't work? How you are testing? What are you expecting to happen? Any log output or exceptions?

Comment: I need to check session by control timeout, because my session never end. I run my web-app, login, go to the page where data get from base(watch tables), and after 30 min. refresh. It refresh and i don't need to login again. This is right or not?if it not right test how can i test that?

Comment: I am not expert in pyramid_beaker, but this is what you need to do. Beaker has an session option ``timeout`` which you should be able to pass to Beaker through pyramid_beaker session interface. https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_beaker/blob/master/pyramid_beaker/__init__.py and https://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=timeout#session-options

Comment: How about adding session.cookie_expires = 3600 where 3600 is seconds.